# NGRX / RXJS: How to recursively map observable streams into a single flat stream

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming, ngrx

I current have the following object structure in an Ngrx Store:

```
    class Case {
      id: string; // an id to uniquely identify the Case
      type: string; // an id to identify the type of the Case
      links: { [ type: string ]: string }; // a dictionary of links to the current Case. 
      // the keys are the type of the Case, and the values are the actual id's of the linked Cases. 
      // These linked cases are in the same store as the Parent Case
    }
```

I can retrieve this case from the store with the method 
`getCase(caseId: string): Observable<Case>` from a `caseService`

I need to create a method that takes the id of a case and queries the store for the case and all of it links. These links need to be retrieved recursively all for all linked cases.

This method needs to return the case, as well as all of it's links, in the following structure:

```
    class CaseLinks {
      case: Case;
      links: { type: string, items: CaseLinks[] }[]
    }
```

Meaning I need a method signature of `getCaseLinks(baseCaseId: string): Observable<CaseLinks>`

Is there anyway that I can query an item from the store and, based off the links in the case, recursively query the store for linked cases and return the result of all of the Observables into a single, flat, observable stream.

Below I have added a Stackblitz containing a small example of the use case and what I want to achieve. Hope this clarifies a few things:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ovpgsh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you already have getCase and getLink selectors, try this code :

```typescript
function getCaseLinks(caseId: string) {
  return this.getCase(caseId).pipe(
    mergeMap(case => combineLatest(case.links.map(link => getLink(link.id))).pipe(
      map(items => ({
        case,
        links: { type: string, items }
      }))
    ))
  )
}
```

Comment: Let's say I add the `getLink` selector. Would that not just return the single case with that ID, basically the same as the `getCase` method? Also would this codeblock not only work for a single level of links instead of drilling down into the link tree? I will still give this a shot though.

Comment: Can you put a real example to show what you're trying to do, please ?

Comment: I have added a stackblitz link to the original question containing a basic example of what I want to do. Hope this clarifies a few things

Comment: Take a look at the expand operator (https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/expand), you can make recursion and stop it based on a condition (in your case, the condition could be empty links property)

Comment: Changed the code a bit to iterate through the keys, and changed the `getLink()` method to `getCaseLinks()` (so that it calls recursively). Added a few break conditions and it works perfectly! Thanks a lot